# Добавить ключ и значение в первый словарь находящийся в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, искусственный-интеллект

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно добавить ещё один ключ и значение в первый словарь находящийся в списке. К примеру "add_key": "add_value"
вот пример списка:

```
media = [{"media": "something", "type": "photo"},
     {"media": "something_else", "type": "photo"}]
```

Что бы по итогу список выглядел так:

```
media = [{"media": "something", "type": "photo", "add_key": "add_value"},
     {"media": "something_else", "type": "photo"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во избежании ошибок советую проверять есть ли первый элемент в массиве

```py
media[0]['add_key'] = 'add_value'
```